# Standard Connection Pool for Connector/Python C Extension?

Tags: python, mysql-connector-python, mysql-connector-c

I am working with MySQL's **Connector/Python C Extension** as I needed access to the originating table for each column in the result.  The C extension provides this via the ‘fetch_fields()’ call, which appears to be unavailable in basic **Connector/Python** (no C extension).

The Connector/Python is equipped with a connection pooling mechanism; e.g. [MySQLConnectionPool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnectionpool.html).  However, I haven't found similar functionality for the C extension.

Is there a standard pooling mechanism for the C extension?  I thought about using **MySQLConnectionPool**’s add connection method to populate the connection pool with C extension connections but the interface to the C extension is quite different than the standard interface so I am expecting this to cause problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection Pooling is not supported by the C Extension in Connector/Python yet.
A `CMySQLConnectionPool` should be implemented. Hacking `MySQLConnectionPool` to use a `CMySQLConnection` object should not work.